# Как сконфигурировать ethernet на эмуляторе android x86 9.0 (qemu/kvm)?

Tags: android, linux, ethernet, qemu, виртуальная-машина

```
netcfg eth0 dhcp
```

не работает.
Говорит нет такой команды... Как сконфигурировать ethernet на эмуляторе android x86 9.0 (qemu/kvm)?

Comment: [Bounty on same question on en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299756/android-ethernet-connection-on-x86-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только сегодня запускал Андроид 9 и Андроид 10 (Bliss 12). Переходишь в меню wifi и включаешь и подключаешься к сети VirtWifi.

Comment: К сожалению мне бы хотелось не использовать wi-fi, а использовать кабельное соеденение... (у меня нет wifi)

Comment: это кабель - просто отображается  так

Comment: кстати если воткнуть ещё вайфай свисток туда - появляется значок провода в трее. дальше посмотреть не получилось - все зависло)